# Search SiteGroups API not working when case sensitive

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, filter, api

I'm using the API to search for sitegroups as below:

```
"/_api/web/SiteGroups?$orderby 'Title'&$select=Id,Title,LoginName" + skiptop + "&$filter=startswith(Title,'" + value + "')"
```

However, I have the problem that in this case, the startswith filter is case sensitive. So, when a user searches for say "App" he gets Approvers, but when he searches for "app" he gets nothing.

**I have tried tolower and other combinations of contains.. substringof..**

*Is there a way making the filter work?*

Comment: I think there are some syntax error in given url, in orderBy and select cause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like given below:

1. Create a new variable for all lowercase value, like:

   ```
   var lowercaseValue = value.toLowerCase();
   ```
2. Then add filter like given below:

   ```
   "$filter=startswith(Title,'" + value + "') or startswith(Title,'" + lowercaseValue + "')"
   ```